# How to overload operators with data from a private member of a string building function

Tags: c++, string, object, operator-overloading

I seem to  be struggling with understanding this particular topic in my class. I was given an assignment with these rules:

Create a class named StringBuilder and split its code into two files: a header file named stringbuilder.h and an implementation file named stringbuilder.cpp.  This class will be used to piece together larger strings from smaller ones. It should have a single private string data member called content. It must also define the following public members:

```
StringBuilder(): a public no-argument constructor that initializes content to an empty string.
StringBuilder(const string& str): a public constructor that takes a string argument and adds it to its content.
const string& str() const: returns its content.
```

This class must also overload the following three operators using member functions:

```
void operator*(unsigned int n):  takes the value of content and add it to itself n times if n is > 1. It should have no impact If n <= 1. This allows you to write something like:
StringBuilder sb("foo"); // sb's content = "foo"
sb * 5; // Now sb's content = "foofoofoofoofoo"

bool operator==(StringBuilder& sb): used to compare two StringBuilder objects. It returns true if the contents of both builders are the same. This allows you to write something like:
StringBuilder sb1("One"), sb2("One");
if(sb1 == sb2){
   cout << "The same";
```

}

```
bool operator!=(StringBuilder& sb): the opposite of operator== returning true of the contents of both builders are different. 
Finally, this class must overload the following two operators using friend functions:

void operator>>(string str, StringBuilder& sb): used for adding a string to the content of a StringBuilder object by writing something like this: 
StringBuilder sb;
"Hello" >> sb; // Now sb contains Hello

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, StringBuilder& sb): used for printing the content of the StringBuilder object to the console by writing something like this:
StringBuilder sb;
cout << sb;
```

In a second .cpp file, write a main() function that tests this class and makes sure it runs as expected. This function must call every constructor/function/overloaded operator in this class.

I coded the class definition as stated here :

```
#ifndef _stringbuilder_h_
#define _stringbuilder_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


class StringBuilder{

    private:
    string content;

    public:
    //Constructors
    StringBuilder():content(""){}
    StringBuilder(const string& str): content(str){}
    const string& str() const{return content;}



    void operator*(unsigned int n);

    bool operator==(StringBuilder& sb);

    bool operator!=(StringBuilder& sb);

    friend void operator>>(string str, StringBuilder& sb);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, StringBuilder& sb);


};

# endif
```

Then I attempted to code it's related implementation as follows:

```
 #include "stringbuilder.h"
    
    
    
    //Member functions
        void operator*(unsigned int n){
           if (n>1){
            return content+=content;
           }
            }
    
        bool operator==(StringBuilder& sb){
            if (sb==content){
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        bool operator!=(StringBuilder& sb){
            if (sb != content){
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        friend void operator>>(string str, StringBuilder& sb){
            cin>> str;
            str = content + sb;
        }
    
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, StringBuilder& sb){
            out<< sb::;
        }
```

The current issues i'm facing now after moving the implementation files from my class definition are now that:
Each operator is highlighted with the error - nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enumeration type

I am unable to reference the value of content because it is a private member

Is there any guidance I could receive in accomplishing this?

Comment: The only remaining problem after modifying the code is with multiplying the string value in the main function as with: ``s1*(3);
    s2*(4);
    cout<<s1<<endl;``. Currently the overloaded operator is as such:  ``    void StringBuilder::operator*(unsigned int n){
       
           cout<<this->content;
        
        }``   but all it does is show s1s2s1 for the cout and then a line with a single iteration of s2's value.
    cout<<s2<<endl;

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `StringBuilder::` to the member functions that are defined outside of the class. e.g. `void StringBuilder::operator*(unsigned int n)`. that should get rid of the  "nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enumeration type" error. there are other errors i noticed while compiling so feel free to let me know if you have trouble with any of those.

Comment: Thanks so much i'll update and see what I can find out.

Comment: I'm getting the error "no operator matches these operands" when I use the code        ``void StringBuilder::operator*(unsigned int n,StringBuilder& sb){
       if (n>1){
        return sb.content*this->content;
       }
        } `` @UnforeseenPrincess

Comment: @ChadrickHollingsworth in there you dont need the return statement, since the function returns void. also as a member function `operator*` should only take one argument, since youre only multiplying the object by one value (`n` in this case).

Comment: I worked my way around it using : `` void StringBuilder::operator*(unsigned int n){
       while (n>1){
        cout<< this->content;
       }n++;
        }`` but now I'm kind of in a rut trying to build out my main.cpp. Cuurently wondering if the instructions ``const string& str() const: returns its content.`` meant I was only supposed to have 2 constructors and the second was meant to be overloaded and use that code to return it's content. @UnforeseenPrincess

Comment: I've almost figured it out. It's just I can't seem to get the value of content to muliply with my code for the *operand. This is what I've got now: ``  void StringBuilder::operator*(unsigned int n){
       
           cout<<this->content;
        
        }`` It gives me an output of the first object combined with the second object and then another of the first object.  Can't quite understand why. I tried using a while loop and it just showed one single iteration of the object.